# Java Logic For Loops // Trying to Create a Deck of Cards

Tags: java, arrays, object, loops

```
public enum Suit
{
    CLUBS,
    HEARTS,
    SPADES,
    DIAMONDS 
}

public enum Value
{
    TWO,
    THREE,
    FOUR,
    FIVE,
    SIX,
    SEVEN,
    EIGHT,
    NINE,
    TEN,
    JACK,
    QUEEN,
    KING,
    ACE
}
```

Card.java

```
public class Card {

    private Suit suit;
    private Value value;

    public Card(Suit theSuit, Value theValue)
    {
        suit = theSuit;
        value = theValue;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return value + " of " + suit;
    }

    public Value getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public Suit getSuit()
    {
        return suit;
    }

    public boolean equals(Card other)
    {
        if (value.ordinal() == other.value.ordinal()
                || suit.ordinal() == other.suit.ordinal())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

CardPile.java

```
public class CardPile

{
    public Card[] cards;

    private int numCards;

    public CardPile()
    {
        this.cards = new Card[52];
        this.numCards = 0;

        // The problem is here, when I try to iterate through the enums and the
        // array to populate my cards[] of 52 objects Card it populates it with
        // 52 Card which are all ACE of DIAMONDS, it looks like the triple loops
        // populates 52 times the two last elements of my enum, but I can't
        // figure out how to fix that! Thanks in advance!

        for (Suit s : Suit.values())
        {
            for (Value v : Value.values())
            {
                for (int π = 0; π < cards.length; π++)
                {
                    cards[π] = new Card(s, v);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
        {
            if (cards[i] != null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int getNumCards()
    {
        return numCards;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you really use `π`?

Comment: I noticed that were missing a for loop here prior to for (Value : v Values()) for Loop there is a for (Suit : s Values()) loop that wrap the 2 loops! Thanks!

Comment: (1) Your for-loop for Suits got lost in the comment and isn't being formatted as code (2) lose the for-loop using pi, it's not needed.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is here:

```
for (int π = 0; π < cards.length; π++) {
    cards[π] = new Card(s, v);
}
```

You're using the same `s` and `v` variables to create your `Card` instance and assign it to all the elements in the `cards` array, replacing every value on every (s, v) pair combination.

Change the code in order to fill it using just the first 2 `for-loop`s:

```
int count = 0;
for (Suit s : Suit.values()) {
    for (Value v : Value.values()) {
        if (count < cards.length) {
            cards[count++] = new Card(s, v);
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, you should not use names as `π` for variables **and** make sure to indent your code.

Answer (score 1):

For every suite and value you iterate over all the 52 cards and set them to be that suit and value. As the last suit/value pair is DIAMOND and ACE, that's what all the cards end up as in the end.

If you get rid of the loop using π, and instead just do:

```
int counter = 0;
for (Suit s : Suit.values())
{
    for (Value v : Value.values())
    {
        cards[counter++] = new Card(s, v);
    }
}
```

Then I think that should work.

Comment: Very similar to my answer except for the `if` validation :).

Comment: I was a bit slow there :) Actually, I think it's better without the `if` validation, because you'd want to know (with an error) if the array was too short, and not have it silently leave some cards out of the deck ;)

Comment: For your comment: I would prefer to change the code after execute it instead of getting an error and breaking the whole program when showing it to somebody else :).

Comment: No need for an if-check if he loses the magic "52" for his Card array, and instead uses Card.values().length * Suit.values().length